# What does it mean to be "t-boned" by something?

Tags: slang

Someone at work today said that "the marketing department might t-bone us with a request for this". What does that mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [literal meaning of "t-bone"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/t-bone) in this context is referring to a type of traffic accident where one vehicle drives into another from the side - generally meaning that vehicle does not see it coming and can't do anything about it.

In this usage it's similar but less literal, it means to be set back by something that you don't see coming.

Comment: I can't find a reference for this particular meaning of the term, I'm afraid!

Comment: @ZoFreX Josh just gave you a reference.

Comment: I think the use of "t-bone" to refer to a type of accident is itself a metaphor (not literal), after the "t-bone" style cut of meat.

Comment: I can't think of a succinct way to word that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

T bone  is where your front  end of vehicle  goes into the side of a vehicle  (mostly happens at junctions or stop signs)

Comment: Despite being a valid answer, I don't think this is the correct context the OP was referencing.

Comment: @JessicaTiberio - But that is the metaphor being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Say it with pictures:

[see the picture from Farmison & Company](https://www.farmison.com/community/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/t-bone-steak.jpg)

You can see the shape of the T. So, imagine the line going up is you, and you are stopped at the horizontal line. If you are in a car, you have hit another car in the middle of its side. That is T-boning a car.  You hit the middle of another car at what is basically a right angle to one of its sides.

It can be used metaphorically too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what T-boning means *in the context in question*.

Comment: T-boning only has one meaning and I have given it.